Adding fixed delay to Update Policy execution
When we define update policy against a specific table , it gets triggered as soon as new data is ingested into the source tables (the sources defined in the update policy definition). But can we add a fixed delay to this behavior ? So let's say new data is ingested into the source tables, I would still like the update policy not to populate data to the target for 30 mins, so in this case 30 min is the fixed delay , can we add this sort of delay?

update policies get triggered when data gets added to the source table. there's no ability to force delays.
perhaps, if you would describe the problem you're trying to solve (without being oriented to a specific solution), it may help with providing you a more appropriate direction.
